# Mpdf - Problem overwriting encrypted files

Tags: php, pdf, output, overwrite, mpdf

I'm having a HUGE problem overwriting encrypted files with mpdf. And I need to overwrite them instead of generating them each time, because the files take a long time to be generated and overwriting them is a powerful strategy that can take few seconds instead of ten minutes. My examples shown below are based on the solution of the example 2 of this [hyperlink](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/overwrite.html). In fact, I can overwrite them when they're generated without encryption. But whenever I try to encrypt I get a blank page that seems useless. And the encryption is essential to avoid piracy.

The code used to generate the pdf is below:

```
<?php
require_once '..\www\vendor\autoload.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->percentSubset = 0;
$mpdf->SetProtection(array(), '', 'bread');   // Need to specify a password

$mpdf->WriteHTML('This copy is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$mpdf->Output('test.pdf','F');

// Have to save various encryption keys, which are uniquely generated each document
$uid = $mpdf->uniqid;
$oval = $mpdf->Ovalue;
$encKey = $mpdf->encryption_key;
$uval = $mpdf->Uvalue;
$pval = $mpdf->Pvalue;
$RC128 = $mpdf->useRC128encryption;

unset($mpdf);    
?>
```

The code used to overwrite the original file is as follows:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); // had to include this to open with google chrome
ini_set('display_errors', 0); // had to include this to open with google chrome
ob_clean(); // had to include this to open with google chrome

require_once '..\www\vendor\autoload.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

// Re-instate saved encryption keys from original document
$mpdf->encrypted = true;
$mpdf->useRC128encryption = $RC128;
$mpdf->uniqid = $uid ;
$mpdf->Ovalue = $oval ;
$mpdf->encryption_key = $encKey ;
$mpdf->Uvalue = $uval ;
$mpdf->Pvalue = $pval ;

$search = array(
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
);

$replacement = array(
    "personalised for Jos\xc3\xa9 Bloggs"
);

$mpdf->OverWrite('test.pdf', $search, $replacement, 'I', 'mpdf.pdf' ) ;
?>
```

I would really appreciate and thank a solution to this problem! Mpdf is great, has many tools, but takes a long time to generate files. Overwriting them is the only solution that can make the end user have a good experience downloading files with their personal data. It would be better yet having a solution that can overwrite with encryption, as the manual says that's possible but i wasn't able to solve myself...

Comment: I'm guessing that those to scripts are not in the same file, since you're require the autolaoder on both? If they are separate, then none the variables you're trying to use (`$RC128`, `$uid`, `$oval`, `$encKey`, `$uval`, `$pval`) won't be defined in the second script, unless you set them somewhere you haven't shown us.

Comment: Hi, Magnus! Thanks for your answer! I understood they should be in separated files because of the output. The output end anything after that line. That is why I thought weird that the variables at the example went after the output. I tried to put them before but had no success. In fact, I had not defined those weird variables at the example, I just used them like the example and no error appeared. Do you think I should try to name variable $RC128 = 'anything'; in both archives to see what happens?

Comment: _"That is why I thought weird that the variables at the example"_ - So this code isn't actually created by you, but a copy of an example? Anyway, you can't expect undefined variables to work as expected. If you have `display_errors` turned on or checked your servers error log, you would at least see some warnings. I would start there and try and sort them out first.

Comment: Hi, Magnus! I made a progress based on your comment that they were in separate files, but it's not the ideal solution to get them working with a single archive to both generate and overwrite. That's because it takes about 10 minutes to generate the file I'm workig on. So, my idea as administrator is to generate the archive a single time, which will serve as the model, so that the rest could be overwritten replacing some text. I was able to do this with separate files, but without encryption.

Comment: Until now, I can't apply SetProtection to any file in a quick way, because mpdf has not a method - that I know -  to add an entire archive, just page by page what increment the total time to many minutes. Is there a way I could post the code to generate and overwrite in a single php file in a comment or just when we create a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it after thinking about the comments and many hours trying and retrying. It is possible to generate a pdf and overwrite with different php pages using mpdf maintaining encryption. When we set encryption, the variables $uid, $oval, $encKey, $RC128, $uval and $pval are generated. Whenever we generate the pdf again, these variables change, so it is important to generate once. After generating, we must send the values of these variables to the server. On the page to overwrite the pdf with client data, maintaing encryption, we must recover these variables from the server so that mpdf can accept to overwrite the encrypted pdf maintaing the encryption in the archive overwritten.

Below there is the code to generate the encrypted pdf and send the variables to the server:

```
<?php 
define('MPDF_PATH','class/mpdf/');
include("../mpdf60/mpdf.php");

$mpdf = new mPDF();
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ob_clean();

$mpdf->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile("testb.pdf");
$mpdf->SetDocTemplate('testb.pdf',true);
  for ($i=1; $i<=$pagecount; $i++) {
       $import_page = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
        $mpdf->UseTemplate($import_page);

        if ($i < $pagecount)
            {$mpdf->AddPage();
    }}

$mpdf->percentSubset = 0;
$mpdf->SetProtection(array(), '', 'yourpassword');   // Need to specify a password

$mpdf->WriteHTML('This copy is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

$mpdf->Output('test.pdf','F');

// Have to save various encryption keys, which are uniquely generated each document
$uid = $mpdf->uniqid;
$oval = $mpdf->Ovalue;
$encKey = $mpdf->encryption_key;
$uval = $mpdf->Uvalue;
$pval = $mpdf->Pvalue;
$RC128 = $mpdf->useRC128encryption;

unset($mpdf);

//==============================================================

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

// Re-instate saved encryption keys from original document
$mpdf->encrypted = true;
$mpdf->useRC128encryption = $RC128;
$mpdf->uniqid = $uid ;
$mpdf->Ovalue = $oval ;
$mpdf->encryption_key = $encKey ;
$mpdf->Uvalue = $uval ;
$mpdf->Pvalue = $pval ;

//Here is the code to update the variables on your server. It is important to already have created a table and have filled the first line with some text in order to update properly 

$sql2= "UPDATE `yourtable` SET `uid`='$uid', `oval`='$oval', `encKey`='$encKey', `uval`='$uval', `pval`='$pval', `RC128`='$RC128' WHERE `pdfline`='firstpdf'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($users, $sql2);
?>
```

After that, the code to overwrite the encrypted file is the following:

```
<?php
define('MPDF_PATH','class/mpdf/');
include("../mpdf60/mpdf.php");

$nomestep1 = mysqli_query ($users, "SELECT `uid` FROM yourtable WHERE `pdfline`='firstpdf'");
$nomestep2 = mysqli_num_rows ($nomestep1);
        for ($i=0 ; $i<$nomestep2 ; $i++)
        {
            $nomestep3 = mysqli_fetch_row($nomestep1);
            echo $nomestep3[0];
            }
$uid = $nomestep3[0];

// In order to illustrate, I showed the recovery from the server of just one variable. The others can be obtained using the same process

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

// Re-instate saved encryption keys from original document
$mpdf->encrypted = true;
$mpdf->useRC128encryption = $RC128;
$mpdf->uniqid = $uid ;
$mpdf->Ovalue = $oval ;
$mpdf->encryption_key = $encKey ;
$mpdf->Uvalue = $uval ;
$mpdf->Pvalue = $pval ;

$search = array(
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
);

$replacement = array(
    "personalised for Jos\xc3\xa9 Bloggs"
);

error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ob_clean();
$mpdf->OverWrite('test.pdf', $search, $replacement, 'I', 'mpdf.pdf' ) ;
?>
```

So that's it. I hope this code might help others the way it has helped me!